# QR code Reader inside the Activity

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing, barcode-scanner

I want to integrate the QR Code reader zxing or any other available lib in my native application but want to integrate the inside my activity layout not to fire Intent and get the result. Desired layout look like the attached screen shot of "QR Droid".

[image]

Please suggest how can I achieve this in my android application.

Answer (score 2):

You should start looking at the ZXing library. I think that is a good fit as it is open source. You can find the relavant code [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fclient%2Fandroid). You'll need to find out exactly how it works, what class does what, and which parts you need. It will be a lot of work though, as it is quite complicated.

Link to full project [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid%253Fstate%253Dclosed). Download it, install it on your phone. Then you can start to make changes, and see how it affects the app. Eventually you should use and adjust the classes you need.